# Column Highchart not zooming in all the way

Tags: highcharts

I have a column highcharts chart that I am trying to enable zooming on. The issue I am having is that when I try and zoom in on a small slice of the chart it always zooms to 200 and not smaller. How can I get it to zoom into the x area I have actually selected? Here is a fiddle showing the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/3gh40fpy/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 1.1
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'series',
    data: [
      [1, 0.4648303],
      [38.6, 0.3659616331],
      [76.2, 0.1323167732],
      [113.8, 0.0300049188],
      [151.4, 0.0049188392],
      [189, 0.0009837678],
      [226.6, 0.0004918839],
      [264.2, 0],
      [301.8, 0],
      [339.4, 0.0004918839],
      [377, 0]
    ]
  }],

  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    zoomType: 'x'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of your chart you should be able to use xAxis.minRange parameter for changing the minimum range to display on xAxis axis:

Documentation:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minRange

```
  xAxis: {
     minRange: 1
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xLzvn73o/

Comment: Thanks. That works for the simple example I posted but for my real program we have a linked axis which this fix doesn't seem to work for. I've posted another fiddle showing that issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/3gh40fpy/1/

Comment: Thanks for second jsFiddle. Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to use linkedTo and add smaller minRange than on master axis.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. If you set the minRange to 1 on both it still doesn't zoom correctly.

Comment: On column chart you xAxis is affected by column pointRange parameter. You can change this parameter if you want your xAxis to zoom correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3gh40fpy/2/